# GUSTIL mv "-bash: gustil: command not found" when trying to move png file to different location

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mv

I'm relatively new to gustil,
I  have .png image on the following location:

"my_bucket/folder/folder1/img.png"

I want to move "img.png" to "folder".

I was trying to do this with the following commands:

```
mv my_bucket/folder/folder1/img.png  my_bucket/folder 

mv my_bucket/folder/folder1/img.png  my_bucket/folder/img.png
```

This fails with the following error:

> No such file or directory

I don't understand where is the mistake.
My goal is to change the location of img.png to be stored inside "folder" and not inside "folder1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with `gsutil` `mv` :

```bash
gsutil mv gs://mazlum_dev/folder/test_column_list2.csv gs://mazlum_dev/input/

gsutil mv gs://mazlum_dev/folder/test_list_column.csv gs://mazlum_dev/input/test_list_column.csv
```

In this case my bucket name is `mazlum_dev`.
I used a `csv` file for this example but it's the same for any kind of files.

You have to be authenticated with an identity having the right permissions on you `Shell` session, where you executing your script (permission given from the `IAM` page on `Google Cloud`).